# Working for one company and reporting to someone in another company

Tags: supervision

We were recently acquired by an "umbrella" company. Are there legal concerns when we hire someone for our company where their payroll and benefits come from our company, but they are required to report to a person in that "umbrella" company?

Comment: Where in the world are you as employment laws vary greatly across the globe?

Comment: Company based in Florida and the umbrella company is in California.

Comment: Have you asked anyone from the "umbrella" company?

Comment: What's the relationship between the companies? Is one of them from overseas? It's common to be hired by an international firm but to have your employment (and payroll, HR, etc) formally administered by a local subsidiary or related business who can handle tax, local employment law, HR, etc.

Answer (score 2):

> We were recently acquired by an "umbrella" company. Are there legal
> concerns when we hire someone for our company where their payroll and
> benefits come from our company, but they are required to report to a
> person in that "umbrella" company?

This isn't unusual. I have worked for decades as a government contractor. In many cases the person who directed my daily activities was a government employee, or even an employee of another company.

What you and your company manger have to understand is who directs your activities and who writes your performance review. Sometimes my non-company manager provided a write up to assist the company manger, sometimes they didn't.

The employee has to spend time keeping all management chains informed regarding performance, vacation, and sick days. This isn't unusual.